# no cuda installed but several nvidia/cuda containers. How to use them?

Tags: docker, cuda

In my ubuntu 20.04 LTS I can do `nvidia-smi`. However I believe CUDA is not installed.

However, I have several docker images named `nvidia/cuda`.

How can I use them to access a container where cuda is installed?

Reference: I believe in the past, I have used CUDA in this computer by running a container that had it installed. I don't remember which image though so I want to do something similar

EDIT

It seems I have been unclear. My ubuntu version is 20.04 LTS that is just information
CUDA is not installed,
However I can program CUDA. How do you say?
Well, I just got a **docker image** which has cuda installed
When I got into the container, cuda is installed.
Unfortunately for some reason this docker image is wrong and produce bad results

So my question is, I have several `nvidia/cuda` images too. How can I use them to build my own container with cuda installed.

Comment: Please see Edit